# How to add a table on Wordpress page without using shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a table using ninja table plugin. I am able to add that table on my page using short code of that table.Now I want to add a table on my page without short code like if I created a new page than I get an option of table customization like add a table, add a row & column delete a row and column etc.

> I already used ninja and tablepress plugin

**Note: Biggest task is to add a table without using short code .**

Comment: From review. Your question should show your effort to solve the task. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Marking question *Unsalvageable*.

Answer (score 0):

Your ultimate goal is to add a table on a page without using any plugin.
The new Gutenberg editor that was launched with WordPress 5.0 allows you to add tables in WordPress easily.

You can follow the steps on [this](https://abhijitrawool.com/insert-a-table-in-wordpress/#method-1) instructions page.

Comment: I already used it ....I have to add a table on my newly created page ...also i don't want to copy and paste the shortcode of that table ...all i wanted a button a custom table add option , row add and coloumn add option on my page without using shorcode